# DAX - Making a calculated column that has another table's value, based on several factors

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I am having trouble with a calculated column I am trying to develop.
I have two tables:

(I don't know why the tables aren't displaying properly. It looks fine in preview)

Table A:

| PK | Calculated column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Value wanted in caluculated column row 1 |
| 2 | Value wanted in caluculated column row 2 |

Table B:

| PK | Table A ID | Wanted Value | Date param |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Value wanted in caluculated column row 1 | 2020/10/08 |
| 2 | 1 | Value not wanted | 2020/04/04 |
| 3 | 2 | Value wanted in caluculated column row 2 | 2021/01/07 |
| 4 | 3 | Value not wanted | 2022/04/12 |
| 5 | 3 | Value wanted in caluculated column row 3 | 2023/01/02 |

What I am stuck on is the DAX code to create a calculated column (Named "Calculated Column" in the example tables) that will take the value from the "Wanted Value" column in table B, based on which Table B row is the most recent regarding the "Date param" column value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

PS: Please tell me if any additional details are required. Also, I normally provide my current code when asking questions on SO, but in this case, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Do you have a relationship between Table A and Table B? Please update table A with the actual output you expect to see in the new column rather than question marks.

Comment: I do have a 1..n relationship from table A to table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Here you go:

```
Calculated column = 
VAR m = CALCULATE( MAX('Table B'[Date param]))
RETURN
CALCULATE( MAX('Table B'[Wanted Value]), 'Table B'[Date param] = m)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, but shouldn’t the calculate filter against the max [date para] column (most recent )?

Comment: You're right! Let me update